# having trouble getting range between two cells

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to determine whether or not any of the cells in a given range have a formula.

I'm using the following function:

```
    public bool noFormulas(Excel.Worksheet dataSheet)
    {
        Excel.Range beginRange=dataSheet.Cells[3, beginColumn];
        Excel.Range endRange=dataSheet.Cells[lastRow, endColumn];

        Excel.Range fullRange = dataSheet.Cells[beginRange,endRange];
        return fullRange.HasFormula == false;
    }
```

where I've declared the interop with:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

The problem is that when the statement assigning the value of `fullRange` is executed, I get 
 this exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'
occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
```

`beginRange` and `endRange` are both being successfully populated; shouldn't I be able to get a range based on its begin and end cells?

Comment: try to change `dataSheet.Cells[beginRange,endRange];` to `dataSheet.Range[beginRange,endRange];`. Also instead `fullRange.HasFormula` you should loop through each cell and check whether any of it has formula (because right now it checks whether _all_ cells in range has formula or not)

Comment: That worked, feel free to post that as the answer.  `fullRange.HasFormula` succeeded; I don't see how looping through individual cells would improve performance.

Comment: don't know about `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`, but in VBA (COM model should be the same), `Range(..).HasFormula` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` when _all_ cells has formula or not. As you mentioned in Q `I'm trying to determine whether or not any of the cells in a given range have a formula.` - so, for determining whethe _any_ cell has formula or not you should use loop (at least in VBA, can't check it right now in C#)

Comment: Verified that this behavior exists in C# as well.  I'll use the loop, thanks for catching that.

Comment: Yeah, I'll update my answer in few minutes:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As follow up from comments, you should change

```
dataSheet.Cells[beginRange,endRange];
```

to

```
dataSheet.Range[beginRange,endRange];
```

Also instead `fullRange.HasFormula` you should loop through each cell and check whether *any* of it has formula (because in your original code it checks whether *all* cells in range has formula or not, and futhermore in situation when you have both cells with formulas and without formulas, `fullRange.HasFormula` throws exception). So, working code is:

```
public bool noFormulas(Excel.Worksheet dataSheet)
{
   Excel.Range beginRange = dataSheet.Cells[3, beginColumn];
   Excel.Range endRange = dataSheet.Cells[lastRow, endColumn];

   Excel.Range fullRange = dataSheet.Range[beginRange, endRange];

   foreach (Excel.Range c in fullRange) 
   {
      if (c.HasFormula)
      {
         return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```